# Using ViewPager / ChildFragmentManager with Android 4.0 and 4.1

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin.android, xamarin

My Xamarin Android app uses fragments for each view rather than separate activities, and one of the fragments needs to contain a ViewPager for a photo slider.

From everything I've seen, the ViewPager has to bind to an adapter that uses fragments. This is problematic because this means I have a fragment within a fragment, which has to use the ChildFragmentManager, which isn't supported in versions prior to Android 4.2. My app needs to work on Android 4.0+, so I need guidance on how to work around this issue.

Some lines of thought I had...

1. Is there a way to bind some other kind of adapter to a ViewPager that doesn't use fragments? In my case all I need is to show an ImageView as each item, so a fragment seems overkill and obviously has the 4.2+ issue.
2. Is there some other control that I could use besides ViewPager that would give me the desired UX (list of photos sliding left/right) without relying on child fragments?
3. Is there a way to make ChildFragmentManager work with Android 4.0 and 4.1?

Current code to setup the ViewPager with only Android 4.2+ support:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:id="@+id/property_details_image_gallery" />

private ViewPager gallery;
gallery = view.FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.property_details_image_gallery);
gallery.Adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter (ChildFragmentManager, 0, facts.PhotoUris);
gallery.SetOnPageChangeListener (this);

public class ImagePagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private int resourceId;
        private List<string> photos;

        public ImagePagerAdapter (FragmentManager fragmentManager, int resourceId, List<string> photos) : base(fragmentManager)
        {
            this.resourceId = resourceId;
            this.photos = photos;
            if (photos.Count == 0)
                photos.Add (string.Empty); // If there are no photos, we add a single photo that will result in a 'noimage' photo
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem (int position)
        {
            // Instantiate a new fragment
            ImageGalleryFragment fragment = new ImageGalleryFragment (photos[position], position);
            return fragment;
        }

        public override long GetItemId (int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override int Count {
            get {
                return photos.Count;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just started using Xamarin 3 days ago, so please be gentle. :)

Comment: Use SupportFragmentManager instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by having ImagePagerAdapter inherit directly from PagerAdapter.

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter {
        private List<string> data;
        private Context context;

        public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, List<string> data) {
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            // Create new image view
            var uri = data [position];
            var imageView = new ImageView(context);
            var defaultImage = context.Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.noimage);
            imageView.SetUrlDrawable (uri, defaultImage);
            // Add image view to pager
            var viewPager = collection as ViewPager;
            viewPager.AddView(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(View collection, int position, Java.Lang.Object view) {
            var viewPager = collection as ViewPager;
            viewPager.RemoveView(view as View);
        }

        public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }

        public override IParcelable SaveState() {
            return null;
        }

        public override void StartUpdate(View arg0) {
        }

        public override void FinishUpdate(View arg0) {
        }

        public override int Count {
            get {
                return data != null ? data.Count : 0;
            }
        }
    }
```